# Renormalize weight matrix using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to add a max norm constraint to several of the weight matrices in my TensorFlow graph, ala Torch's [`renorm`](http://torch7.readthedocs.org/en/rtd/maths/#torchrenormres-x-p-dim-maxnorm) method.

If the L2 norm of any neuron's weight matrix exceeds `max_norm`, I'd like to scale its weights down so that their L2 norm is exactly `max_norm`.

What's the best way to express this using TensorFlow?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def maxnorm_regularizer(threshold, axes=1, name="maxnorm", collection="maxnorm"):
    def maxnorm(weights):
        clipped = tf.clip_by_norm(weights, clip_norm=threshold, axes=axes)
        clip_weights = tf.assign(weights, clipped, name=name)
        tf.add_to_collection(collection, clip_weights)
        return None # there is no regularization loss term
    return maxnorm
```

Here's how you would use it:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import fully_connected
from tensorflow.contrib.framework import arg_scope

with arg_scope(
        [fully_connected],
        weights_regularizer=max_norm_regularizer(1.5)):
    hidden1 = fully_connected(X, 200, scope="hidden1")
    hidden2 = fully_connected(hidden1, 100, scope="hidden2")
    outputs = fully_connected(hidden2, 5, activation_fn=None, scope="outs")

max_norm_ops = tf.get_collection("max_norm")

[...]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for X_batch, y_batch in load_next_batch():
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
            sess.run(max_norm_ops)
```

This creates a 3 layer neural network and trains it with max norm regularization at every layer (with a threshold of 1.5). I just tried it, seems to work. Hope this helps! Suggestions for improvements are welcome. :)

**Notes**

This code is based on `tf.clip_by_norm()`:

```
>>> x = tf.constant([0., 0., 3., 4., 30., 40., 300., 400.], shape=(4, 2))
>>> print(x.eval())
[[   0.    0.]
 [   3.    4.]
 [  30.   40.]
 [ 300.  400.]]
>>> clip_rows = tf.clip_by_norm(x, clip_norm=10, axes=1)
>>> print(clip_rows.eval())
[[ 0.          0.        ]
 [ 3.          4.        ]
 [ 6.          8.        ]  # clipped!
 [ 6.00000048  8.        ]] # clipped!
```

You can also clip columns if you need to:

```
>>> clip_cols = tf.clip_by_norm(x, clip_norm=350, axes=0)
>>> print(clip_cols.eval())
[[   0.            0.        ]
 [   3.            3.48245788]
 [  30.           34.82457733]
 [ 300.          348.24578857]]
                # clipped!
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Rafał's suggestion and TensorFlow's [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a5d8217c4ed90041bea2616c14a8ddcf11ec8c03/tensorflow/python/ops/clip_ops.py#L90-L95) of `clip_by_norm`, here's what I came up with:

```
def renorm(x, axis, max_norm):
    '''Renormalizes the sub-tensors along axis such that they do not exceed norm max_norm.'''
    # This elaborate dance avoids empty slices, which TF dislikes.
    rank = tf.rank(x)
    bigrange = tf.range(-1, rank + 1)
    dims = tf.slice(
                tf.concat(0, [tf.slice(bigrange, [0], [1 + axis]),
                              tf.slice(bigrange, [axis + 2], [-1])]),
                [1], rank - [1])

    # Determine which columns need to be renormalized.
    l2norm_inv = tf.rsqrt(tf.reduce_sum(x * x, dims, keep_dims=True))
    scale = max_norm * tf.minimum(l2norm_inv, tf.constant(1.0 / max_norm))

    # Broadcast the scalings
    return tf.mul(scale, x)
```

It seems to have the desired behavior for 2-dimensional matrices and should 
generalize to tensors:

```
> x = tf.constant([0., 0., 3., 4., 30., 40., 300., 400.], shape=(4, 2))
> print x.eval()
[[   0.    0.]  # rows have norms of 0, 5, 50, 500
 [   3.    4.]  # cols have norms of ~302, ~402
 [  30.   40.]
 [ 300.  400.]]
> print renorm(x, 0, 10).eval()
[[ 0.          0.        ]  # unaffected
 [ 3.          4.        ]  # unaffected
 [ 5.99999952  7.99999952]  # rescaled
 [ 6.00000048  8.00000095]] # rescaled
> print renorm(x, 1, 350).eval()
[[   0.            0.        ]  # col 0 is unaffected
 [   3.            3.48245788]  # col 1 is rescaled
 [  30.           34.82457733]
 [ 300.          348.24578857]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [clip_by_norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#clip_by_norm) function, which does exactly this. It takes a single tensor as input and returns a scaled down tensor.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! That looks very close to what I want, only it applies to the entire matrix, whereas I'd like to renormalize each column independently (ala Torch's renorm). Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps by replacing the [`reduce_sum` call](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b11337ea5719a8799f279a41c2cd5c9e75a8acf7/tensorflow/python/ops/clip_ops.py#L90-L93) in `clip_by_norm` with something that sets [`reduction_indices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduce_sum)?

Comment: Ah, from the question it looked like you want to normalize the whole matrix using its norm and not columns separately.

Comment: Yes, adding parameter to reduce_sum to aggregate by a given row or column will be sufficient to get the norms.

Also, we need to update the final matrix with independent values. The simple trick to solve this is by additionally parameter keep_dims=True and letting the broadcasting handle everything. The final change would be:

`reduction_axis = 1  # or 0 for rows`

`reduce_sum(t * t, reduction_axis, keep_dims=True)`

Comment: I converted these suggestions into a new answer. Feedback would be welcome, in particular on whether there's a better way to generate lists like `[0, 1, 3, 4]`: ranges with one element missing.

Comment: Nice! I think you can replace the concat with something like: `tf.pack([bigrange[:1 + axis], bigrange[2 + axis:]])`, which is a bit cleaner.