# Tensorflow: Implementing maxnorm, does one have to do it via operations on the graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I want to use maxnorming, meaning that columns of the weight matrices are normalized once their euclidean norm becomes too large.

Ideally I'd do it like

```
def renorm_weights(w, b, max_norm):
     l2norm_inv_scaled = max_norm * tf.rsqrt(tf.reduce_sum(w**2, reduction_indices=0))
     scale =  tf.minimum(l2norm_inv_scaled, tf.constant(1.0))
     return (tf.mul(w, scale), tf.mul(b, scale))
```

And then I can use it like

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Variable init
    # Training
    for i in range(len(weights)):
         weights[i], biases[i] = renorm_weights(weights[i], biases[i], max_norm=#)
```

But as far as I am aware this is not possible in tensorflow, as these operations must be defined on the graph before the session is created (and a function is independent of the graph).

My question is am I correct in thinking is and is the method I propose instead okay.

So I think I will have to do it like this instead. Where my graph is being setup:

```
    max_norm = #
    l2norm_inv_sc = []
    scale = []
    renorm_op = []
    for i in range(len(weights)):
             l2norm_inv_sc.append(max_norm * tf.rsqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(weights[i]), reduction_indices=0)))
             scale.append(tf.minimum(l2norm_inv_sc[i], tf.constant(1.0)))
             renorm_op.append((tf.assign(weights[i], tf.mul(weights[i], scale[i])), tf.assign(biases[i], tf.mul(biases[i], scale[i]))))
```

Could of course use a `placeholder` for `max_norm` but nevermind that for now. 
Which I would then use like

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Variable init
    # Training
    for i in range(len(weights)):
         sess.run(renorm_op[i][0])
         sess.run(renorm_op[i][1])
```

Comment: This does not help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934303/renormalize-weight-matrix-using-tensorflow/34934673#34934673

Comment: That does it per tensor, so instead of working with the columns it would do it for the whole matrix.

Comment: I think if you read the comments and/or scroll a tad bit upwards, it shows how to do it either with columsn or rows, no?

Comment: You're right. Sorry. I remember looking at it before and thought I had confirmed it couldn't do that. But I don't think that will work well because then I'll only be adjusting the weights and not the bias. I think when I scale a column of weights I have to also scale the bias corresponding to that neuron the column belongs to.

Comment: I see. The suggested solution in the linked thread can be extended in a straightforward way to your setting with scaling down the bias weights, too.

Comment: To re-emphasize: `tf.clip_by_norm` does what you want --- it can clip along columns or rows depending on the `axes` parameter. If you want to scale the biases using the same scaling factor, you could create your own variant of clip_by_norm that does this. It should be a straightforward modification of the existing `tf.clip_by_norm`. You can find the Tensorflow implementation here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/clip_ops.py#L62